# How to check which pages are part of an extent?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, dbcc-checkdb

I have some data corruption and was not able to restore the data via backups. It was affecting mainly non-clustered indexes, so after drop-create of the indexes the issues were resolved.

Finally, I have:

> Msg 8905, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Extent (1:896320) in database ID
> 15 is marked allocated in the GAM, but no SGAM or IAM has allocated
> it. CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors not
> associated with any single object. CHECKDB found 1 allocation errors
> and 0 consistency errors in database 'db_name'. repair_allow_data_loss
> is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB
> (db_name).

I want to find which are the extent pages and then to see what's the data in these pages. Then, to decide to run the *CHECHDB* command with *repair_allow_data_loss* or save some data if possible.

Comment: [dbcc checkdb returns error](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/dbcc-checkdb-returns-error) has a comment by Paul Randal you might be interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to find which are the extent pages [...]

It tells you in the error, `Extent (1:896320)`, so from page 1:896320 to 1:896327.

The thing here is that you have an allocation error where the extent is marked as allocated but no other structure shows it as such. Is it really part of something? Is is not?

> [...] and then to see what's the data in these pages.

I get where you're coming from, however, it's unknown when the pages are from. This could have been something that happened a while ago and it's just being noticed, so let's say for argument sake that there is data there. Is it from 6 months ago? Yesterday? You're really not going to know. What if it's part of a text tree? The point is that the only safe thing to do is generally deallocate the extent. No other allocation structures are claiming it and you don't know when it's from.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the pages and really I am not able to understand there data. Also, the `DBCC PAGE` is not able to extract the row data. Last question - is there a command to deallocate only this extent and not running the `DBCC CHECKDB` which is slow?

Comment: CheckDB is the way to go @gotqn - it takes time to run because it's checking the facts of the database.